# pygame instantly quits window

Tags: python

Why is the window instantly closing?
I am trying to follow this tutorial so far everything is a coppy but it doesnt work
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jO6qQDNa2UY
there is lines under

```
pygame.QUIT():
    run = False
```

```py
import pygame

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 900, 500
WIN = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))


def main():

    run = True
    while run:

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT():
                run = False
    pygame.quit()


if __name__ == "__main_":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

Not a python guy, but I think the last line should be

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: this is right, but indentation needs exactly 4 spaces

Comment: @blankettripod it *should* be four spaces, but it doesn't *need* to. Even if the rest of the program is written with four spaces (to some extent).

Answer (score 0):

BlackBeans is on the correct track about the typo in your "if" statement.  Also, though, there needs to be a "pygame.init()" call at the beginning of the program as well.  Plus "pygame.QUIT()" actually should be "pygame.QUIT".  With those bits of information, the following code snippet presents a black screen until the window is closed.

```
import pygame

pygame.init()   # This is needed

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 900, 500
WIN = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))

def main():
    print("Entered main")
    run = True
    while run:
    
        

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:  # Omit the "()"
                print("Quitting")
                run = False
                
        pygame.display.update()
    pygame.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":  
    main()
```

Give that a go to see if you progress further in your game development.